# docker-compose build // error - (root) Additional property nginx is not allowed

Tags: docker, консоль, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

Я хочу создать сборку docker.
Я изучаю это репо: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/user-interface-api/install-sample-app?trail_id=force_com_dev_intermediate
Я клонирую это репо: https://github.com/forcedotcom/RecordViewer
Когда я использую docker-compose build у меня ошибка (root) Additional property nginx is not allowed.
если я пишу в docker.compose.yml какой-нибудь другой код из интернета, то команда выполняется. Что мне нужно изменить, чтобы команда работала для этого docker-compose.yml?  Если я удалю nginx, ошибка выглядит так: error - (root) Additional property web is not allowed.

[image: (root) Дополнительное свойство nginx не разрешено]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса.

Comment: всем привет, код есть на github. перерыл весь интернет и не нашёл никакого решения.

Comment: этому репозиторию уже 4 года, там старый синтаксис и в issues есть упоминание этого и примерный фикс: https://github.com/forcedotcom/RecordViewer/issues/52

Comment: спасибо тебе большое, в Trail нигде не было указано. Я нуб в гите и не знал про это, очень долго искал решение, спасибо. Да и вообще Docker для Windows какая-то сложная тема для входа. я её устанавливал часов 5. То Hyper V включить, то команды какие-то подключить к Powershell, то Sharing Drivers сделать активным. Просто шаг за шагом. Примерное время выполнения модуля ~30 минут. Нормальные такие 30 минут у меня вышли...

Answer (score 0):

(с)
этому репозиторию уже 4 года, там старый синтаксис и в issues есть упоминание этого и примерный фикс: github.com/forcedotcom/RecordViewer/issues/52 –
Exploding Kitten
проблема решена, спасибо.